# Syntax error not found insert into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query who insert data on temporary table like this:

```
INSERT INTO ##TGJAE
    SELECT
        TT.RECID, TT.TRANSDATE,
        TT.DATAAREAID, TT.SOURCERECID,
        TT.SOURCECURRENCYCODE, TT.TAXAMOUNT,
        TT.TAXBASEAMOUNT, TT.TAXBASEAMOUNTCUR,
        TT.TAXAMOUNTCUR, TT.TAXORIGIN, TT.VOUCHER,
        TT.TAXITEMGROUP, TT.TAXCODE, 
        TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR, TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR,
        TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP,
        TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,
        TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
        GJAERIVA.TEXT, GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
        GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
    FROM 
        TAXTRANS TT 
    INNER MERGE JOIN 
        TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
    INNER MERGE JOIN 
        GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
                                            AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN (14, 236, 71, 41) 
                                            AND TT.TRANSDATE <= '2017-06-30'
    WHERE 
        (TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11 AND 
         TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2016-06-30'  AND '2017-06-30') 
        OR 
        (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND 
         TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30' )) AS T
```

For some reason at the end of query throws an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

[image]

I check it eternal times but I don´t get any wrong. Can someone view something wrong? Regards

Comment: Have you tried removing that second paren and the `as T`? It looks like you're trying to make a subquery out of the thing (wrapping it in parens and aliasing it, but you ever have an opening paren, nor do you use it as a subquery or CTE anywhere. If you drop the `) as T` I think it should work just fine.

Comment: The last close parenthesis has no matching open parenthesis

Comment: That is a temporary table not a temporal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no open parenthesis to match the close paren that is highlighted.

Comment: If I remove one parenthesis I have same error but saying` Incorrect synatx Near ´AS´`, I can´t use "AS" clause in where?

Comment: @Ledwing Why do you need an alias for inserting data?

Comment: You´re right. I confused with another structure. Thanks